# How to compute this Z-Transform?

Tags: recurrence-relations, z-transform

The exercise is like this:
$$y(k+1) - 3y(k) = 4^k$$

How do I compute $Z$ transform of $4^k$?

I understand that I have to use the Z-Transform formula
and the result after applying it is :

$$sum [(4^k)/(z^k)] $$

How can this be continued?

Comment: So, Homework???

Comment: It's just some practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x(n) = (4^n) u(n)$$

$$X(z) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} x(n) z^{-n}$$

$$X(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 4^{n} z^{-n}$$

$$X(z) = 1 + \frac{4}{z} + \frac{4^2}{z^2} + .......$$

Geometric Series

$$X(z) = \frac{1}{(1-\frac{4}{z})}$$